# Loop Until then click on the element

Tags: loops, selenium-webdriver, while-loop, do-while

I want to click a view more button till a certain linktext element is visible then click on that link text. How would I go about creating that loop? I tried different methods but still not getting it right:

```
WebElement viewmorebutton = wdriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/input"));
                    while(checkButton(viewmorebutton)){
                        wdriver.findElement(By.id(TransationListingWeb.getView_more_transactions_button_id())).click();
                        if( wdriver.findElement(By.linkText("LOTTO (20-03-2019)")).isDisplayed()){
                            wdriver.findElement(By.linkText("LOTTO (20-03-2019)")).click();

                        }else
                            wdriver.findElement(By.id(TransationListingWeb.getView_more_transactions_button_id())).click();
                }
```